# Is there a way to toggle vpn on and off programmatically in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, vpn

is there a way to toggle vpn on and off programmatically in iOS?

I need to know iOS Private API for VPN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, iOS doesn't allow to access the data network related settings..

Answer (score 1):

*Asked the same question 2 days ago. Unfortunately there is no api/framework so far. But, CISCO and Juniper apps implements this using their private frameworks. As for now there is nothing we could do programmatically, other than asking users to change the settings.*

Comment: i want to know private frameworks api......

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to toogle VPN, Wi-Fi or bluetooth now.

Comment: i can user private frameworks.wifi is [[objc_getClass("SBWiFiManager") sharedInstance] setWiFiEnabled:enabled];  and bluetooth is [[objc_getClass("BluetoothManager") sharedInstance] setPowered:enabled];

Comment: do you know the private frameworks api?